# Google sign-in button not working in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I have a firebase app that requires users to be authenticated using Google.
I managed to hook up all settings and users can read/write to their prospective database location on firebase.

The only issue is: I am trying to display the Google-Sign-In button inside a chrome extension pop up. Here is my `manifest.json`

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name" : "MY EXTENSION",
    "version" : "0.0.6",
    "browser_action" : {
        "default_popup" : "welcome.html"
    },
    "background" : {
        "scripts" : ["js/jquery.min.js","js/firebase.js","js/firebase_config.js","js/background.js"],
        "persistent" : false
    },
    "oauth2" : {
        "client_id" : "686230544294-m9jfmc18cneiandadq8riborrjmq36in.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "scopes" : [
            "openid", "email", "profile"
        ]
    },
    "content_security_policy" : "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'"

}
```

Here is my `welcome.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
        <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="686230544294-m9jfmc18cneiandadq8riborrjmq36in.apps.googleusercontent.com">

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome. Please sign in</h1>
        <div id="my-signin2"></div>

        <script src="js/google_config.js"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The pop up opens up with everything except for the button. When I inspect its console, I get the following error:

> `Uncaught uO
>   message: "Invalid cookiePolicy"stack: "gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy↵    at new uO (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.iUeg......`

From firebase side, I can see users signing in. 
What am I doing wrong? why doesn't the Sign-In button show up on the extension pop up?

Comment: Hi Ahmad, was you able to fix it? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @KanakSony I gave up and had to use FireBase authentication

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan to request additional OAuth scope and are just using this for authentication and not authorization, Firebase Auth `signInWithPopup` will take care of signing in a user to Google directly for you in Chrome Extensions as long as you whitelist your chrome extension domain: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#authenticate_with_firebase_in_a_chrome_extension

Comment: Hi, I need to authenticate and then call google calendar APIs after signing in. This works fine if I authenticate and call calendar APIs immediately but fails with an authenticated user saved in LOCAL session.

Comment: In that case, you are better off using the google sign in js library as they manage OAuth tokens for you. Firebase Auth is only focused on AuthN and not AuthZ.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have given up after trying to integrate gapi.js. Google sign-in does not work for chrome extensions, it fails with "Invalid Cookie Policy". That;'s why moved to Firebase.

Comment: Ah I see. Have you checked out this sample code on GitHub: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/chromextension